# Smalltalk Seaside display in threes without using tables

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

I have built a web site for my local plastic model club which involves showing multiple images on a page. I like to show them 3 abreast. Up to now, I have done this using a nested series of table codes which gets very messy.

Is there a simpler way. Let us say that I have 12 images and I want to show them three across and 4 rows down. I can do this using html table, html table row, etc. but it gets very complicated with lots of if statements, etc.

As I have had problems maintaining the web site from day to day, I have taken down the seaside version but you can see an example of the type of display on the current home page at http://www.ipms-clacton.org.uk under "A selection of member's models"

David

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the table programmatically you could use the following code as a new message in your class.  If you pass it the **html** and an **orderedCollection** it makes a new table 3 items wide and as many rows as it takes.  The final row can be less than three elements.  You will need to change it to display images rather than text but it's a place to start.  The ***removeFirst:*** command removes a number of items from an ordered collection and returns those items as a new collection.  That lets you break the collection apart into elements for your individual rows.  Here is the message's definition:

```
make3Table: html using: anOrdCollection

html table: [ 
    [ anOrdCollection size >= 3 ] whileTrue: [ html tableRow: [
        (anOrdCollection removeFirst: 3) do: [ :item | html tableData: item ]
        ].
    ].
    anOrdCollection isNotEmpty ifTrue: [ 
        html tableRow: [ 
            anOrdCollection do: [  :item |  html tableData: item ]
        ]
    ].
]
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you. After all these years of using Smalltalk, I had never thought of using removeFirst in that way. Thanks again.
David

Comment: You're introducing mutation of an argument by introducing that removeFirst: send. I'd avoid this approach since it introduces complexity and code duplication.

Comment: Esteban has a good point: my way wipes out the collection being sent  with the message.  I could have added a `tempOrderedCollection := anOrderedCollection copy.`  and mutated the temporary collection instead.

Comment: I got this to work except that removeFirst: and isNotEmpty are not included in VisuageAge so I had to write them. Apart from that, it works very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't Seaside specific, but HTML/CSS related.

The solution for that is to use any element inside a container, and use CSS-grid layout for that container.

E.g.

```css
.gallery-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .gallery-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .gallery-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="image-container"></div>
    <div class="image-container">2</div>
    <div class="image-container">3</div>
    <div class="image-container">4</div>
    <div class="image-container">5</div>
    <div class="image-container">6</div>
    <div class="image-container">7</div>
    <div class="image-container">8</div>
    <div class="image-container">9</div>
    <div class="image-container">10</div>
  </div>

</html>
```

It will work for any number of elements, and it has two CSS width breakpoints to show 1, 2 or 4 elements per row.

Then the Seaside part is only about generating that container and the elements using the canvas tags.

Comment: Thank you Esteban. However, I am trying to keep within Seaside for clarity. Passing a lot of HTML to a page doesn't seem to me to be best practice.

Comment: This is not a Seaside question. It's an HTML/CSS question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a table another couple simpler ways to do it with css + seaside is with CSS columns:

```
html div 
    style:'columns:3';
    with:[ myCollection do:[:ea | html div:ea]]
```

There are several css styling [rules for columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns).

Or using [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
html div 
    style:'display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content: space-between';
    with:[
          myCollection do:[:ea | html div 
                                      style:'width:32%'; 
                                      with: ea]
          ]
```

Those `style:` rules could/should be in your CSS file as a CSS class